# Counting the occurrence of alphanumeric characters and printing them graphically

Tags: java, string

I have a string, and I want to count the occurrence of all letters and numbers and want to create a graph so I can see the occurrence graphically.

So for example:

```
String sentence = "ABC ABC ABC 123"

A (3) * * *
B (3) * * *
C (3) * * *
D
.
.
```

My way of thinking:

1. Count all numbers and letters in the string
2. Print all asterisks times this number (unfortunately I can't multiply a String with an int in Java)

I think there are two ways of counting the characters. I can either use the `charAt()` method or `toCharArray()` and loop through the string or array and count the letters.

For example:

```
aCounter = 0;
bCounter = 0;
char ch = sentence.charAt(i);

for (i = 0; i < sentence.length(); ++i) {
    if (ch == 'a') {
        aCounter++;
    }
    if (ch == 'b') {
        bCounter++;
    }
}
```

However, I have multiple problems with this approach:

- I would have a to make a lot of counter variables - `aCounter` through `zCounter` plus `0counter` through `9counter`
- I would have to make another for loop to print the asterisks!

I'm not asking for an set answer here, I'm just looking for some good directions, because I'm stuck.

Comment: use a hashmap, using the characters as the map keys. then it's a simple matter of (in pseudo-code) `map[character]++`.

Comment: Oh, you want the number of occurence of each character. Duh. Knew this seemed TOO easy. Not that it isn't easy. Marc B has the right idea.

Comment: You could use a `Map<Char, Integer>` or even an array, since you know how many characters + numbers are in the alphabet.

Comment: Does case matter? or should A and a be treated the same?

Comment: var charCount = 0
     var c = null;
     for (var i = 0; i < newPwd.value.length; i++) {
      c = newPwd.value.substring(i, i + 1)
      if (isNaN(parseInt(c)) == true) {
       charCount++
      } 
     }

Comment: I suggest using an array of `int[]` rather than incurring the overhead of a `HashMap`. It would be interesting to see the performance of my example vs. a `HashMap` example.

Answer (score 8):

*There's no need to make a `HashTable/HashMap/HashSet` for this.*

**You know which characters are being tracked ahead of time, so you can use an array.**

> I want to count the occurrence of all letters and numbers

Make a string of the characters you will track, then initialize an array.

```
String sentence = "ABC ABC ABC 123";

//Make a map of all the characters you want to track.
String indexes = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

//Initialize an array to the size of the possible matches.
int[] count = new int[indexes.length()];

//Loop through the sentence looking for matches.
for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
    //This will get the index in the array, if it's a character we are tracking
    int index = indexes.indexOf(sentence.charAt(i));

    //If it's not a character we are tracking, indexOf returns -1, so skip those.
    if (index < 0)
        continue;

    count[index]++;
}
```

Then you can print them all out with this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
    if (count[i] < 1)
        continue;

    System.out.println(String.format("%s (%d) %s",
            indexes.charAt(i),
            count[i],
            //This little bit of magic creates a string of nul bytes, then replaces it with asterisks.
            new String(new char[count[i]]).replace('\0', '*')));
}
```

If you aren't comfortable with the `new String(new char[count[i]]).replace('\0', '*'))` bit, then you can use a `StringBuilder` to build the asterisk `String` before trying to output it. You can see ***@mike***'s example below for a good example of that.

#### Outputs

```
1 (1) *
2 (1) *
3 (1) *
A (3) ***
B (3) ***
C (3) ***
```

#### Considerations

Here are some things to consider when decided how to solve this problem.

- Will you always know what characters need to be tracked ahead of time, or will there be times when you want to track *any* character? In the latter case, an array won't work for you; you would need to use an advanced data structure like a TreeMap or HashMap.
- Will you always be counting occurrences of specific `char`s, as opposed to `String`s? If you have to modify this to count `String`s then using the `String indexes` map trick isn't going to work for you either.
- Are you learning a specific data structure(s) in your course at the moment? Usually problems such as this are assigned to students to understand how to apply a specific concept. As ***@kyle*** suggested, you should try to use the data structure that you are learning about, or have learned about, in your class. *Sometimes using structures that you haven't learned about yet can get you in trouble, or a lower grade at least.*

Comment: I've added another approach... quite an overkill. If I have time I'll create a third one with as less lines of code as possible.

Comment: While it is true that you don't need a `HashMap`, it is a data structure fit for the task (well, actually a MultiSet is, but we don't have that one in Java standard libraries). Your approach works for _most_ of the inputs well, but what if I happen to live in a country that has special characters like "ěščřžýáíé"? What if I forgot some ("ůúňťď")? Also, invoking `indexOf()` on every iteration works, but I am curious about its performance with looooooong input strings. All and all, while this works, I wouldn't say it's a way to go with modern Java approaches existing. This is 1990s calling again

Comment: @Slanec `indexOf` is called on the map of characters being tracked, not on the input string itself. Also, read my **considerations** section, and you will see that the other points you made are already in my answer.

Comment: @crush I feel bad, and am sorry. I have to shamefully admit I didn't read that section. It indeed tells the whole story. And yes, I am aware of the `indexOf()` usage and I would be still worried. It's still linear probing and while in small scale it's nothing, if the `indexes` array were longer and we had lots of input, it might be noticable. It's a good approach for educational purposes, though, so yeah.

Comment: @Slanec No need to be shameful! I do it all the time ;)

Comment: I have to counter your first consideration. An array will always work if `char`s are considered, since they have a fixed size of 2 byte.

Comment: @mike It wouldn't work because you don't know how big to make the array initially. `any` character means you don't know what all characters you are tracking, so you need to track any character encountered, thus, you'd either need to allocate the array to some enormous size that may go wasted, or you'd need to reallocate the array as it grows - hence a good case to use a data structure like a `HashMap`.

Comment: I did it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18787187/1809463 Since a char has a fixed size of 16bit , there are 2^16 = 65536 possible assignments for a `char`.

Comment: @Mike right - and most of those elements go wasted because 90% of them won't be present in the input string.

Comment: @crush it would only require 256kB memory. Not a big deal on modern machines. But yes, there still would be many unused ints left.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints to get you started:

1. Don't use a separate variable for each counter.  Use an array (or some collection type ... if you have been taught about that ...).
2. You can use a character as an array index.
3. Accumulate all of the counts before you start printing anything.

Comment: @mike Sometimes code makes for a better explanation. =) This is a nice summation of my implementation below, though. It is abstract! +1

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looping once to calculate the amount, and looping a second time to print the asterisks, you can use another approach:

```
Map<Character,String> results = new HashMap<Character, String>();
```

Then, each time you iterate, you check if your map contains data for the character and, if it doesn't, you initialize it. In pseudocode:

```
If the map contains data for the key
    Obtain the data for the character
    append a new asterisk
Else
    Create a String with an asterisk
    Append an asterisk
    Put the String with the character as key
```

If you ever need the amount of asterisks as a number, you can always obtain the size of that `String` (assuming you don't put any whitespaces).

---

#### Update

As an enhancement, taking into account the comments I shared with @crush, two tweaks can improve the logic:

- *`StringBuilder` instead of `String`:* Avoid unnecessary creation of literals.
- *`TreeMap` instead of `HashMap`:* It would give the proper order to the map, allowing a sorted printing of its content.

It's up to the OP to add this extra stuff, if there's room (and knowledge) enough to justify their use.

Comment: Don't forget to update the number of occurrences in the `String` too. Remember, the format is `A (3) ***` so you'd have to update the count as well. In the end, you still have to iterate over the map to display each `String` in it after you've built them all.

Comment: @crush The count is the size of the stored string. and Indeed, you need to iterate over the map, but you have all the information there. It's a single iteration to display the results in the end.

Comment: Oh, I missed that you were simply storing a string of asterisks. So in the end, you'd have something like `String.format("%s (%d) %s", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().length(), entry.getValue());`

Comment: @crush For example, yes, if the OP knows about `String#Format`. Otherwise, a simple concatenation works too :)

Comment: I think that your answer isn't getting the attention it deserves. For example, my answer would require three loops, if not for the `String.replace()` business (which technically is looping internally). This approach will only require two loops. I'd rather see the use of a `TreeMap` though, I think. Going back to my array example, though, an array of `String` could accomplish the same result, but the concatenations would be nasty because it would be creating a new immutable `String` on each loop.

Comment: @crush And I upvoted yours for that clever use of indexes ;). Indeed, `TreeMap` would be a good tweak in order to print the values with the proper order, given that `Character` comes with a `compareTo` implementation. I'd say to keep the `String` approach, since I'm not quite sure the OP knows about `StringBuilder`. At first I used builders instead of raw `Strings` but went for a simpler approach in order to mantain a certain degree of simplicity, bot this two points are a good update.

Answer (score 2):

Here an OOP approach, that uses [`StringReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) and a Map. I used `TreeMap`
to have the ouput sorted.

```java
public class StringHistogram
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please insert string: ");
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    sc.close();
    System.out.println(s);

    StringReader r = new StringReader(s);

    Map<Character, Integer> histogram = new TreeMap<Character, Integer>();
    int c;
    while ((c = r.read()) != -1) {
      Integer count = histogram.get((char) c);
      if (count == null)
        count = 0;
      histogram.put((char) c, count + 1);
    }
    r.close();
    for (Entry<Character, Integer> entry : histogram.entrySet())
      System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " (" + entry.getValue()
          + ") " + createAsterisk(entry.getValue()));
  }

  private static String createAsterisk(int number) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
      sb.append("*");
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create a hashtable and go through the string, add each time the current char to the hashtable

```
     String str = "abc abc abc 123";
     Hashtable numbers = new Hashtable();
     int size = str.length();
     for(int i = 0 ; i< size ; i++)
     {
         char curr = str.charAt(i);
         if(numbers.contains(curr) == false)
         {
             numbers.put(curr, 1);
         }
         else
         {
             numbers.put(curr, ((int)numbers.get(curr)) + 1);
         }
     }

     Enumeration names = numbers.keys();
     char c;

     while(names.hasMoreElements()) {
        c = (char) names.nextElement();
        System.out.println(c + ": " +
        numbers.get(c));
     }
```

Comment: This is a clean approach. Don't forget to address the printing of the output (the asterisks question) with your answer!

Comment: @crush added that. nice name btw

Comment: `Hashtable` and `Enumeration` - what year is this? :) (Modern code would use `HashMap` and `Iterator`)

Answer (score 1):

Use an array to store the counters. You can use a char directly as an array index, so you don't need complex logic.

To print a given number of asterisks, a for loop is the easiest way.

Comment: The easiest way would be what @crush did `new String(new char[count[i]]).replace('\0', '*'))`

Comment: What's "easiest" is debatable - creating an array full of NUL characters, creating a string from that array, and creating another string where each NUL character is replaced by an asterisk is non-trivial and inefficient. It's a neat trick though.

Comment: @Joni More efficient would be using a StringBuilder, but then you end up with at least 2-3 more lines of code depending on how you write it out. String concatenation in a for loop would perform remarkably worse, though. I don't get your comment about it being `non-trivial`. It seems pretty trivial to me.

Comment: @crush I used a `StringBuilder` in the answer I posted. ...but I've always had a faible for one-liners :D ...I think with non-trivial he meant it's kind of hackish and not the first approach that comes to ones mind.

Comment: If you want to print a given number of asterisks, the first thing that comes to mind is a loop that prints them one by one. Constructing a string is a step up in the abstraction ladder...

Comment: Okay. I didn't equate non-trivial with that, but I understand what you mean now. `StringBuilder` is perhaps the best solution for printing `n` asterisks, as @mike does in his example.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are new to this and don't already have the solution (Which is where everyone starts), the *right* answer is to use the data structure that you are learning in class.

If you are learning Maps

- TreeMap sorts but natural order of the key (Nice for printing)
- HashMap doesn't have a very predictable ordering

If you are learning arrays, there are great examples in this thread already ex. response from crush

Comment: Excellent point. This simply shouldn't be overlooked. Since this is a homework assignment, it is important to apply what you are learning in class to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Divide it into two methods** -- one to create a String "row" given a char and a String, and one to call the first method for each of the 36 alphanumeric chars.

```
public static String alphNum = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";

    public static String count(char c, String str) {
        String stringToReturn = Character.toString(c);
        for(char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
            if (ch == c) {
                stringToReturn += " *";
            }
        }
        return stringToReturn;
    }

    public static void countAndPrintAlphNum(String str) {
        String stringToTest = str.toUpperCase();
        Set<String> rows = new HashSet<String>();
        char[] alphNumArray = alphNum.toCharArray();
        for(char c : alphNumArray) {
            rows.add(count(c, stringToTest));
        }
        for(String row : rows) {
            System.out.println(row);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        countAndPrintAlphNum("Hi There 123!");
    }
```

Note:  If you want to ensure that the rows are printed in alpha - numeric order (with the numbers first), use a TreeSet instead of a HashSet for the rows.

Comment: @crush This is true, yes.  By "ensure" I was thinking of programming defensively (in case the alphNum String is not in order).  Of course, on the other hand, perhaps having the numbers last is desired and so we'd just use a HashSet.

Answer (score 0):

Since, we're living in times of cloud computing and parallelism. Here another approach.

```java
public class DistributedHistogram
{
  private static final int PORT = 1337;
  private static final String LOOPBACK = "127.0.13.37";

  public static final byte[] DATA = new byte[] {(byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF};
  public static final byte[] STOP = new byte[] {(byte) 0xDE, (byte) 0xAD};

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException
  {
    ExecutorService se = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    se.submit(new Server(PORT, 16));

    System.out.print("Please insert string: ");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = s.nextLine();
    s.close();
    System.out.println(input);

    ExecutorService ce = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(16);
    List<Future<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<Void>>();
    for (char c : input.toCharArray())
      futures.add(ce.submit(new Client(new Character[]{c}, DATA, LOOPBACK, PORT)));

    /* wait for the clients to complete before we send stop to server */
    for (Future<Void> f : futures)
    {
      try
      {
        @SuppressWarnings ("unused")
        Void v = f.get();
      }
      catch (ExecutionException e)
      {
        //...
      }
    }
    ce.submit(new StopClient(LOOPBACK, PORT)); // sends stop signal

    ce.shutdown();
    se.shutdown();
  }
}

class Client implements Callable<Void>
{
  private final Character[] chars;
  private final String ip;
  private final int port;
  private final byte[] type;

  public Client(Character[] chars, byte[] type, String ip, int port)
  {
    this.chars = chars;
    this.type = type;
    this.ip = ip;
    this.port = port;
  }

  @Override
  public Void call() throws Exception
  {
    Socket s = new Socket(ip, port);
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    for (Character c : chars) {
      out.write(type);
      out.writeChar(c);
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    s.close();
    return null;
  }
}

class StopClient extends Client {

  public StopClient(String ip, int port)
  {
    super(new Character[]{' '}, DistributedHistogram.STOP, ip, port);
  }
}

class Server implements Callable<Void>
{
  private final int port;
  private ServerSocket ss;
  private final ExecutorService e;

  private final ConcurrentHistogram ch = new ConcurrentHistogram();
  private final AtomicInteger client = new AtomicInteger();

  private AtomicBoolean quit = new AtomicBoolean(false);

  public Server(int port, int clients)
  {
    this.port = port;
    this.e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(clients);
  }

  public ConcurrentHistogram getHistogram() { return ch; }

  public void stop()
  {
    quit.set(true);
    e.submit(new Callable<Void>()
    {
      @Override
      public Void call() throws Exception
      {
        Thread.sleep(250);
        ss.close();
        return null;
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public Void call() throws Exception
  {
    ss = new ServerSocket(port);
    while (!quit.get() && !ss.isClosed())
    {
      try
      {
        e.submit(new ClientHandler(client.getAndIncrement(), ss.accept(), this));
      }
      catch (SocketException se)
      { continue; }
    }
    e.shutdown();
    System.out.println(ch.toString());
    while (!e.isTerminated()) { /* wait */ }
    return null;
  }
}

class ConcurrentHistogram
{
  private final ConcurrentMap<Character, AtomicInteger> histogram = new ConcurrentHashMap<Character, AtomicInteger>();
  private static final String HISTOGRAM_CHAR = "*";

  public ConcurrentMap<Character, AtomicInteger> getHistogram() { return histogram; }

  private String createAsterisk(int number)
  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
      sb.append(HISTOGRAM_CHAR);
    return sb.toString();
  }

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    List<Entry<Character, AtomicInteger>> data = new ArrayList<Entry<Character, AtomicInteger>>(histogram.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<Entry<Character, AtomicInteger>>()
    {
      @Override
      public int compare(Entry<Character, AtomicInteger> o1, Entry<Character, AtomicInteger> o2)
      {
        return o1.getKey().compareTo(o2.getKey());
      }
    });
    for (Entry<Character, AtomicInteger> entry : data)
    {
      int value = entry.getValue().get();
      sb.append(entry.getKey() + " " + String.format("%4s", "(" + value + ")") + " " + createAsterisk(value) + "\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public void addChar(Character c)
  {
    AtomicInteger value = histogram.get(c);
    if (value == null)
    {
      histogram.putIfAbsent(c, new AtomicInteger());
      value = histogram.get(c);
    }
    value.incrementAndGet();
  }
}

class ClientHandler implements Callable<Void>
{
  @SuppressWarnings ("unused")
  private final int client;
  private final Socket s;

  private final Server server;

  public ClientHandler(int client, Socket s, Server server)
  {
    this.client = client;
    this.s = s;
    this.server = server;
  }

  @Override
  public Void call() throws Exception
  {
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    int c;
    int i = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[2];
    while ((c = in.read()) != -1)
    {
      if (i < 2)
      { bytes[i++] = ((byte) c); }
      else if (Arrays.equals(bytes, DistributedHistogram.DATA))
      {
        i = 0;
        char ch = (char) (((c & 0x00FF) << 8) + (in.read() & 0x00FF));
        server.getHistogram().addChar(ch);
      }
      else if (Arrays.equals(bytes, DistributedHistogram.STOP))
      {
        i = 0;
        server.stop();
      }
      else
      { i = 0; }
    }
    in.close();
    s.close();
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hahah. This would be a good approach if counting the occurrences of characters in the Bible.

Comment: :D Took my a while, to get the server to quit *after* the last message is sent. Waiting with `f.get()` alone, did not help, I've had to add a delay before closing the server socket... Btw I've added a third and last solution. It's as short as possible. At least I think so.

Answer (score 0):

Here, a last, minimalistic **not** OOP answer. With effectively 3 lines. It works, because chars can be interpreted as integers.
I was a little concerned about not closing the scanner. But since the javadoc says `System.in`
 `is already open and ready to supply input data`. I assume that the closing of the resource is also handled by the system.

```
public class MinimalisticHistogram
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int[] occurrences = new int[(int) Math.pow(2, 16)]; // 256 KB
    for (char c : new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().toCharArray()) occurrences[c]++;
    for (int i = 0; i < occurrences.length; i++) if (occurrences[i] != 0) System.out.println(String.format("%c %4s %s", i, "(" + occurrences[i] + ")", new String(new char[occurrences[i]]).replace('\0', '*')));
  }
}
```

Comment: You cheated by stringing a bunch of statements onto that final line ;)

Answer (score 0):

So I used an double for loop the count the characters. If a character was matched in one of the arrays the count was added in the third array.

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < zinArray.length; i++) {
>     char c = zinArray[i];
>     for (int j = 0; j < controleArray.length; j++) { 
>         char d = controleArray[j];      
>         if (c == d) {
>         letterCount[j]++;
>         break; 
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

this is how I did the algorithm with StringBuffer

```
public class StringManipulation {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int occurrences = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int firstLoc = 0;
    int lastLoc = 0;
    boolean countedMulti = false;

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    String a = new String("ABC ABC ABC 123");
    String lastStrChar = null;

    char tempChar = 'z';

    while (count <= a.length()-1) 
    {
        for (int scanner = 48; scanner <= 90; scanner++) 
        {

            if (a.charAt(count) == scanner) {
                tempChar = (char)scanner;

                for (int i = 0; i <= a.length() - 1; i++) 
                {

                    if (tempChar == a.charAt(i)) {

                        if (count == 0) 
                        {
                            occurrences += 1;

                            sb.append(tempChar);
                        }

                        if (count > 0) {
                            if (a.charAt(count) != a.charAt(count - 1)) 
                            {
                                occurrences += 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (count == i + 1) 
                    {
                        sb.append(tempChar);
                        occurrences = 0;
                    }

                    if ((sb.length() - 1) >= 0) 
                    {
                        lastStrChar = sb.substring(sb.length() - 1);

                        firstLoc = sb.indexOf(sb.substring(sb.length() - 1));
                        lastLoc = sb.length() - 1;

                        if (count>0 && sb.lastIndexOf(lastStrChar,firstLoc) != sb.lastIndexOf(lastStrChar, lastLoc)) 
                        {
                            countedMulti = true; //if the index is different for the same character, a duplicate char is found
                        } 
                        else 
                        {                           
                            countedMulti = false;               
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (!countedMulti) 
                {
                    System.out.print(lastStrChar + " appeared " + occurrences + " times\n");    
                }
            }
        }

        count++;
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> A appeared 3 times
> B appeared 3 times
> C appeared 3 times
> 1 appeared 1 times
> 2 appeared 1 times
> 3 appeared 1 times
> ```